# Clear form after submit image in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I’m using CFS for files upload in my Meteor App, almost everything works fine, except because when I try to upload another image, I see my previous sended image in the form, so I need to clear that form after submit the image. I've tried with .reset but it doesn't work. This is my code right now. Thanks for the help.

**NewImage.html**

```
<template name="newImage">
    <div align="center">
      <form align="center">
        <div>
          <div>
            <span class="btn btn-success btn-file">
              <input type="file" accept=".gif,.jpg,.png" class="myFileInputimagepub" id="image"/>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src="{{currentUser.profile.image}}" alt="Image" width="60px" height="60px" class="img-circle avatar-upload" value=''/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </template>
```

**NewImage.js**

```
import './newImage.html';

Template.NewImage.events({
  'change .myFileInputimagepub':function(evt,tmpl){
    FS.Utility.eachFile(event,function(file){
      fileImagespub.insert(file,function(err,fileObj){
        if(!err){
          var userId = Meteor.userId();
          var imageurl = {
            'profile.image':'/cfs/files/fileimages/' + fileObj._id
          };
          setTimeout(function(){
            Meteor.users.update(userId,{$set:imageurl});
          },2000);
        }
      })
    })
  },

  'submit form':function(event,template){
    event.preventDefault();
    template.find("form").reset();
  }
});
```

Comment: (1) Is the image that is sticking around the one rendered with `<img src="{{currentUser.profile.image}}"...` (2) Why are you allowing multiple images to be dropped when the user's profile can only have a single image (3) Why the `setTimeout` on updating the user object? (4) The rendered image is not an input element so it can't be "reset"

Answer (score 2):

If the image in question is the one with class `.img-circle`, the issue is that its `src` attribute is being dynamically provided. Currently it is `currentUser.profile.image`. This won't clear just by resetting the form and manually clearing the image's `src` value would be fighting the framework.

### Option 1 (Not Ideal):

If you don't want to keep the image, unset the database change made after the file upload by running something like this:

```
Meteor.users.update(userId, { $set: { 'profile.image': null }});
```

*This is not ideal as it enables you to continue modifying the database with an image which may not be needed long-term.*

*Additionally, I'm assuming you're currently using the autopublish/insecure packages. You'll want to remove these before going public with your app as they allow any user to change the database without restriction.*

### Option 2:

You could save the returned value from your `'change .myFileInputimagepub'` event as a [ReactiveVar](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html), then only actually run `Meteor.users.update` (preferably on the server using a [Method](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html)) when your user submits the form. At that point you could clear the reactive variable.

Using a ReactiveVar will allow you to provide the saved URL to the `src` attribute via a helper, and then change the ReactiveVar's value when you wish to clear the form.

There's a simple example of manipulating ReactiveVars here: https://gist.github.com/ahoereth/a75d2d6528b1844ad503

Comment: Thanks Dom. The First option doesn't work, but right now I'm trying with the second one, the Reactive Var to accomplish this.

Comment: Swell. That's a better way to do it. Please post source code if you have issues using ReactiveVar.